# Why is einsum faster than numpy.correlate on floats, but slower on complex numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Trying to figure out the fastest implementation of a correlation on some complex numbers - data shape is a 1d array of length ~1e5, and a characteristic kernel length is ~20.  Inner1d can't take complex numbers, and fft convolutions aren't efficient with this kernel size, so the two methods I've been testing are np.correlate and einsum.

With floats, einsum combined with a sliding window using as_strided is a bit faster than np.correlate.

```
data = np.ones(1e5, dtype='float64')
kernel = np.ones(20, dtype='float64')

%timeit xc1 = np.correlate(data, kernel)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.13 ms per loop

%timeit xc2 = np.einsum("ij,j->i", as_strided(data, shape=(data.shape[0]-(kernel.shape[0]-1), kernel.shape[0]), strides=data.strides * 2), kernel)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 ms per loop
```

But then with complex numbers, einsum is significantly slower than np.correlate...

```
data = np.ones(1e5, dtype='complex128')
kernel = np.ones(20, dtype='complex128')
data_conj = np.empty(data.shape[0], dtype='complex128')
data_conj = np.conj(data)

%timeit xc1 = np.correlate(data, kernel)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.21 ms per loop

%timeit xc2 = np.einsum("ij,j->i", as_strided(data_conj, shape=(data_conj.shape[0]-(kernel.shape[0]-1), kernel.shape[0]), strides=data_conj.strides * 2), kernel)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.78 ms per loop
```

I think I understand why einsum is taking longer than before, but how is np.correlate barely taking any more time than with the floats?  Is there a complex math trick I might be able to take advantage of with the einsum?

For what its worth, splitting up the einsum correlation into the real and imaginary components is faster, but still much slower than np.correlate.

```
%timeit xc3 = np.einsum("ij,j->i", as_strided(data_Re, shape=(data_Re.shape[0]-(kernel_Re.shape[0]-1), kernel_Re.shape[0]), strides=data_Re.strides * 2), kernel_Re) + np.einsum("ij,j->i", as_strided(data_Im, shape=(data_Im.shape[0]-(kernel_Im.shape[0]-1), kernel_Im.shape[0]), strides=data_Im.strides * 2), kernel_Im)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.21 ms per loop
```